# Summing radio input values

Tags: javascript

I'm new to this so I have been trying to adapt code from others to suit my needs, I need a radio selection from the first name group to be added to the second name group and then displayed in the text box at the bottom.

Nothing appears in the bottom text box. Where am I going wrong?

Javascript:

```
$("input[type=radio]").click(function() 
{
    var total = 0;
    $("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function() 
    {
        total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });

    $("#totalSum").val(total);
});
```

HTML:

```
<strong>Choose a base package:</strong>
<input id="item_0" type="radio" name="pkg" value="1942" />Base Package 1 - $1942
<input id="item_1" type="radio" name="pkg" value="2313" />Base Package 2 - $2313
<input id="item_2" type="radio" name="pkg" value="2829" />Base Package 3 - $2829
<strong>Choose an add on:</strong>
<input id="item_10" type="radio" name="ext" value="0" />No add-on - +$0
<input id="item_12" type="radio" name="ext" value="2146" />Add-on 1 - (+$2146)
<input id="item_13" type="radio" name="ext" value="2455" />Add-on 2 - (+$2455)
<input id="item_14" type="radio" name="ext" value="2764" />Add-on 3 - (+$2764)
<input id="item_15" type="radio" name="ext" value="3073" />Add-on 4 - (+$3073)
<input id="item_16" type="radio" name="ext" value="3382" />Add-on 5 - (+$3382)
<input id="item_17" type="radio" name="ext" value="3691" />Add-on 6 - (+$3691)
<strong>Your total is:</strong>
<input id="totalSum" type="text" name="totalSum" readonly="readonly" size="5" value="" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your javascript is executed before the HTML is generated, so it doesn't "see" the ungenerated INPUT elements. For jQuery, you would either stick the Javascript at the end of the HTML or wrap it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() { //jQuery trick to say after all the HTML is parsed.
    $("input[type=radio]").click(function() {
      var total = 0;
      $("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function() {
        total += parseFloat($(this).val());
      });

      $("#totalSum").val(total);
    });
  });
</script>
```

*EDIT: This code works for me*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <strong>Choose a base package:</strong>
  <input id="item_0" type="radio" name="pkg" value="1942" />Base Package 1 - $1942
  <input id="item_1" type="radio" name="pkg" value="2313" />Base Package 2 - $2313
  <input id="item_2" type="radio" name="pkg" value="2829" />Base Package 3 - $2829
  <strong>Choose an add on:</strong>
  <input id="item_10" type="radio" name="ext" value="0" />No add-on - +$0
  <input id="item_12" type="radio" name="ext" value="2146" />Add-on 1 - (+$2146)
  <input id="item_13" type="radio" name="ext" value="2455" />Add-on 2 - (+$2455)
  <input id="item_14" type="radio" name="ext" value="2764" />Add-on 3 - (+$2764)
  <input id="item_15" type="radio" name="ext" value="3073" />Add-on 4 - (+$3073)
  <input id="item_16" type="radio" name="ext" value="3382" />Add-on 5 - (+$3382)
  <input id="item_17" type="radio" name="ext" value="3691" />Add-on 6 - (+$3691)
  <strong>Your total is:</strong>
  <input id="totalSum" type="text" name="totalSum" readonly="readonly" size="5" value="" />
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $("input[type=radio]").click(function() {
        var total = 0;
        $("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function() {
          total += parseFloat($(this).val());
        });

        $("#totalSum").val(total);
      });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I still can't get it to work, tried the script at the end of the html. The .click should wait for the radio inputs shouldn't it? Have I constructed the textbox correctly?

Comment: Can you post a fiddle or the full HTML & JS? - Actually, see my edit above.

Comment: @tjunior You have no library selected, so `$` is meaningless.  In my code above, I show you how and where to include the jQuery library for it to work.